# Conditional Expectation problem of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability

An individual experiences a loss due to property damage and a loss due to bodily injury. Losses are independent and uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 3]$.

Calculate the expected loss due to bodily injury, given that at least one of the losses is less than $1$.

Attempt:

$X = $loss due to property, $Y =$ loss due to bodily injury.
 We want to find the following: $E(Y|X\,\cup \, Y<1)$

$X\,\cup\,Y<1$ on two intervals, $0<x<1, 0<y<3$ and $0<x<3, 0<y<1$

I don't actually have any clue how to proceed from here. I tried:

$$E(X\,\cup\,Y<1)\over P(X\,\cup\,Y<1)$$ But I don't think that will help me since I couldn't figure out how to do either of those things.

Comment: I think people usually do not condense $X < 1 \cup Y < 1$ as $X \cup Y < 1$, as $X, Y$ are random variables while $X < 1,  Y < 1$ are events. For these kind of problem, usually you start from the conditional CDF: $\displaystyle \Pr\{Y \leq y|X < 1 \cup Y < 1\} = \frac {\Pr\{Y \leq y \cap (X < 1 \cup Y < 1)\}} {\Pr\{Y < 1 \cup X < 1\}}$. The numerator is $\Pr\{(Y \leq y \cap X < 1) \cup (Y \leq y \cap Y < 1)\} = \Pr\{Y \leq y \cap X < 1\} + \Pr\{Y \leq \min\{y,1\}\} - \Pr\{Y \leq \min\{y, 1\} \cap X < 1\}$. So by independence all terms can be worked out and the denominator is similar.

Comment: I don't see what that gives me though, is doing the CDF giving me the expected value? I'm just not seeing what this does in terms of solving the problem. @BGM

Comment: If you know the CDF of a distribution, then you can have everything - the corresponding pdf, the moments etc...